# Php shell_exec return running process ID

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to return a process ID throw a php.
In Linux this command return Process ID

> /receive.sh url=http://www.site.com 
>   cert=certs/test_lv.p12?test_lv  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &

I need to run this command throw a php.

```
$response2 = shell_exec("./receive.sh url=https://www.site.com cert=certs/test.p12?test_lv  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
 echo $response2;
```

It's returned an empty string.
Thanks for answers!

Updated*
I added an ouput PID and it works! Thanks to all!

> ```
> ./receive.sh url=https://www.site.com cert=certs/test_lv.p12?test_lv  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &  echo $!
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you code has a bug since it already redirects the output to /dev/null in your command , 
just try to remove the output redirection and it may work

Answer (score 1):

shell_exec returns the output stream. Your command may print the process id to the error stream and that's why you get an empty string.

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#55632) you can see how to print the error stream. I am not sure if that's your case but give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php).